# Animate both background and content

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate splash screen here I am able to animate the logo but when I try to animate the background overall animation effect not working.
I tried here https://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/yu2afj7b/:
Here is my scss:

```
 .container {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: #ddd;
   margin: 20px;
 }

 .page {
   //Intro Screen
   &__intro {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     img {
       width: 150px;
       transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     }
     &-wrapper {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 10;
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       background: #fff;
       text-align: center;
     }
     &--hidden {
       img {
         width: 0;
         transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page__intro-wrapper">
    <div class="page__intro">
      <img src="http://szmob.rbahn.com/img/sz-logo.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to animate .page__intro-wrapper background ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your post you are trying to anymate div with a class `.page__intro-wrapper`. The issue is in your scss, yuo are adding `.page__intro--hidden` class to the image which is inside that class but not the needed div.
In other words, change this:

```
 &--hidden {
   img {
     width: 0;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   }
 }
```

to this:

```
 &--hidden {
   img {
     width: 0 !important;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   }
     width: 0 !important;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/yu2afj7b/3/